# How to import tables with images from a webpage to a spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, image, import, spreadsheet

I saw a table online "https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/Fish_(New_Horizons)" which I want to import into my excel (or free alternatives like google sheet),
I know how to use import table from web, but it doesn't import images.
Alternatively, upon simple copy and paste, the images are all anchored to the wrong cells and I cannot sort them or edit them correctly.

Google sheet has the command `=image("http://example.com/image.jpg")` that put images into a cell however that requires heavy manual work, but at least this proves the end product I want can be done.

I have resorted to using Numbers on Mac as it supports simple copy and paste of tables that has images within cells, however Numbers is proprietary on Macs and I don't see helpful export options.

So, ultimately I want to share it with my friends, is there a way to import tables with images into a spreadsheet software like Excel, or better, Google sheet?